# dev server for serving assets with headers

Tags: http, templates, client-side-templating

i am trying to serve template assets that can be used like this:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="todo-item-template" src="todo-item-template.xhtml">
```

which means i need to set headers on the asset that line up with the script type.

is there a way to do this using some sort of development appserver off the filesystem? I'm trying to architect a workflow that lets our frontend folks work without running against our real backend.

something as simple as `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` except that lets me configure headers for certain extensions, would be great. it would be simple to code myself, but would rather go with an existing solution because there may be more unforseen problems.